# How to handle dbContext in azure functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am writing an Azure function V2 in C# (ASP.NET core). I want to write REST API which performs database operations using EF. How to manage the dbContext so that it will work on local machine and cloud as well.

Comment: What is your exact problem with dbContext? Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: @walkerbox The dbcontext is static inside azure function. what if there are multiple azure functions..do i have to create dbcontext object each time ? if yes is there any data concurrency and consistency issue?

Comment: First of all, DbContext is related to ASP.NET Core. Azure Functions can be written in C# (the language, not the ASP.NET Core framework). If you want to create an Azure Function where you want to write the controller in ASP.NET Core and from that you can trigger a HTTPTrigger in Azure Functions, where you can perform on atomic unit of work using that Azure Function. You can read more about it here, https://markheath.net/post/azure-functions-rest-csharp-bindings

Comment: @IshamMohamed What about running migrations and dealing with monolithic application.

Comment: You can still do the migrations in the traditional way. Migrations are something that is being done by the developer of the application.

Comment: thanks @IshamMohamed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I agree with what @Ishan Mohammed has mentioned in the comment.

If you want to add a connection string from the azure portal. You can try this:

From your Function App UI, click Function App Settings

Settings / Application Settings

Add connection strings

They will then be available using the same logic as if they were in a web.config, e.g.

```
var conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
             .ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
```

In order to configure your Azure functions to use EF's DB context, ensure to add these dependencies if you haven't added them earlier.

“Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore” and

“Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer“.

You can go through the below articles for more info [Here](https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/build-elegant-rest-apis-with-azure-functions/)

This is another useful documentation which might be of your help.

[Azure Functions with EF](https://serversncode.com/azure-functions-entity-framework-part-2/)